# browser rotates video

Tags: ffmpeg

I use `ffmpeg` to convert a `3gp` video to `MP4`. You can see a part of output of `ffmpeg` here:

```
ffmpeg version N-79139-gde1a0d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
```

...

```
Input #0, 

...
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : ...
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         :                                
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    ...
```

I use `noautorotate` option in below command to avoid auto rotate based on metadata of file and it is successful:

> ffmpeg -noautorotate -i $vid -qscale 0 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128k ../MP4/$(basename $vid).mp4

Then I tried this HTML code to open converted file in a browser(for example by `Google Chrome`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="../videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I open that, video shown rotated. How I can solve this problem? Is there a tag or any other thing to disable autorotate in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `noautorotate` stops FFmpeg from rotating the video, it does not remove the rotation tag from the output. So, you have to set the tag manually.

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i $vid .....  -metadata:s:v rotate=0 output.mp4
```